# GLSL atomicMin/Max for float without SPV_EXT_shader_atomic_float_min_max

Tags: graphics, floating-point, glsl, atomic, vulkan

So because my GPU RTX3000 series doesn't have support for **VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_SHADER_ATOMIC_FLOAT_2_FEATURES_EXT**, maybe it is supported by some Intel APUs? [ATOMIC_FLOAT_2](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Registry/blob/master/extensions/EXT/SPV_EXT_shader_atomic_float_min_max.html).

Anyway, I would like an alternative to access and compare atomically some float fields. It is kind of weird this functionality it is not mandatory in the whole GPU ecosystem cause as far as I know native format of data in GPU architecture is floating points. I don't know. Any idea?

So I tried to active this feature but all the fields in the atomic struct are returned as zero (not supported).

```
VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures2 features2 = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_FEATURES_2};
    VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan13Features vulkan_1_3_features = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_3_FEATURES};
    VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features vulkan_1_2_features = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_2_FEATURES};
    VkPhysicalDeviceVulkan11Features vulkan_1_1_features = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_VULKAN_1_1_FEATURES};
    // https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceAccelerationStructureFeaturesKHR.html
    VkPhysicalDeviceAccelerationStructureFeaturesKHR acceleration_structure_features = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_FEATURES_KHR};
    // https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceRayTracingPipelineFeaturesKHR.html
    VkPhysicalDeviceRayTracingPipelineFeaturesKHR ray_tracing_pipeline_features = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_RAY_TRACING_PIPELINE_FEATURES_KHR};
    // https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceRayQueryFeaturesKHR.html
    VkPhysicalDeviceRayQueryFeaturesKHR ray_query_features = {VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_RAY_QUERY_FEATURES_KHR};
    // https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceShaderAtomicFloatFeaturesEXT.html
    VkPhysicalDeviceShaderAtomicFloatFeaturesEXT shader_atomic_float_features = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_SHADER_ATOMIC_FLOAT_FEATURES_EXT};
    VkPhysicalDeviceShaderAtomicFloat2FeaturesEXT shader_atomic_float2_features = {
        VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_SHADER_ATOMIC_FLOAT_2_FEATURES_EXT};

    features2.pNext = &vulkan_1_3_features;
    vulkan_1_3_features.pNext = &vulkan_1_2_features;
    vulkan_1_2_features.pNext = &vulkan_1_1_features;
    vulkan_1_1_features.pNext = &acceleration_structure_features;
    acceleration_structure_features.pNext = &ray_tracing_pipeline_features;
    ray_tracing_pipeline_features.pNext = &ray_query_features;
    ray_query_features.pNext = &shader_atomic_float_features;
    shader_atomic_float_features.pNext = &shader_atomic_float2_features;

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures2(context->device.physical_device, &features2);
```

If I tried to use it I lose my device...

```
#version 450
#extension GLSL_EXT_shader_atomic_float2: require
...

shared float min_distance;

main(){
...
atomicMin(min_distance);
}
```

Comment: "*native format of data in GPU architecture is floating points.*" I don't know what that means, but it sounds dubious. GPUs have had integer support since the GL 3.x days.

Comment: You are right. Integers are widely implemented in hardware by many vendor GPU archs but float are still the main register type. Why don't GPU support min max atomic functions for floats but they do for int, uint, int64 and uint64? It sounds kind of weird.